# Assignment of rank1 array in fortran

Tags: arrays, fortran, variable-assignment

Whenever I compile the following fortran code:

```
program test
    implicit none
    integer     :: temp(1),i
    integer     :: z(1:10) = [(i,i=1,10)]

    temp(1) = 10
    z(2)    = temp

end program test
```

I get the error:error #6366: The shapes of the array expressions do not conform
If I change the line:

```
z(2)    = temp
```

to

```
z(2)    = temp(1)
```

It compiles and runs fine. Why can't you assign a single element array to an element of another array without having to explicitly list the element. I ask this because some intrinsic functions like minloc and pack return rank 1 values. So for example:
z(i) = minloc(z) produces the same error.

Answer (score 9):

> Why can't you assign a single element
>   array to an element of another array
>   without having to explicitly list the
>   element.

According to Fortran standard the arrays ranks should be compatible upon the assignment. You can find the definition of compatibility in that document. For example, in Fortran 2003 Standard, section **7.4.1.2 Intrinsic assignment statement**

> (2) Either variable shall be an allocatable array of the same rank as expr or the shapes of
>   variable and expr shall conform

and section **2.4.5 Array** gives us the definitions:

> An array may have up to seven dimensions, and any extent (number of elements) in any dimension.
>   The rank of the array is the number of dimensions; its size is the total number of elements, which is
>   equal to the product of the extents. An array may have zero size. The shape of an array is determined
>   by its rank and its extent in each dimension, and may be represented as a rank-one array whose elements
>   are the extents.
>   [...]
>   Two arrays are conformable if they have the same shape.

Now take a look at your code. z(2) is scalar. It's rank is 0. It's shape is zero-sized array. temp is array with rank 1 and shape [1]. Shapes are different. This two entities are not conformable.

But you can make them if you want. You can use array sections:

```
z(2:2)    = temp
```

Now shape of both entities is [1].